# Sharepoint REST API access token does not return all sites

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get all the sites in Sharepoint Online using a Sharepoint Add-in App's access token. When I do so I only get 17 of the 35 sites that I can see when viewing all of the sites in the admin portal.

It's also worth noting that when I use an access token from an azure app, making the same call I get all the apps.

**What is the difference? How can I get all the sites using the sharepoint token?**

This is the admin portal link where i can see all the sites:

```
https://<MY-TENANT>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement
```

This is where I created my Sharepoint App:

```
https://<MY-TENANT>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
```

And here are the permissions I gave it:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

For the Working Azure App, I registered the app in the azure portal and assigned these permissions:

```
MS GRAPH API:
    Profile
    Sites.FullControl.All
    Group.ReadWrite.All
SHAREPOINT API:
    Sites.FullControl.All
    TermStore.Read.All
    User.ReadWrite.All
```

The same rest call I'm using in both cases is:

```
https://<MY-TENANT>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site%20contentclass:STS_Web'&selectproperties='UniqueId,Title,SiteName,Path,Description,contentclass'&startrow=0&rowlimit=100
```

**UPDATE:**

Using a client_credentials access_token seemed to give me all the sites, whereas the authorization_code access_token did not... Code flow is generally better, Ideally I would use that, but maybe given the configuration of the app it doesn't make sense here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand what the issue was:

We were trying to use OAuth Code Flow ('authorization_code' grant_type) with the app. Sharepoint does support this, however it doesn't support the "FullControl" right when requesting access in this manner. So instead we had been putting in the "Manage" right. When using the Manage right we were effectively reducing our permissions. This prevented us from calling paths such as: /_api/web/roleassignments

when switching to use the client_credentials flow we started seeing the same results as the azure app's access_token.